# How to check the collection reading count in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes Firebase as the backend for my application.

I have noticed an increase in Firebase reading counts, and I suspect that a particular collection might be causing this issue.

I only know the total reading count of my project.

However, I'm not sure how to check the count of reading documents in a collection.

Could someone please guide me on how to determine the count of documents within a specific collection in Firebase?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone please guide me on how to determine the count of documents within a specific collection in Firebase?

Firestore provides counting only for the total number of reads for the entire database. If you need to know the count of documents in a specific collection, then you'll have to record that yourself. The simplest solution I can think of would be to [increment a numeric value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) each time a document within that specific collection is read.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't provide a way to monitor the usage of a single collection.  The dashboard only provides the usage of the entire database.  You can't break that down into individual collections.

If you want to record the number of reads, you will have to do that yourself somehow.